# App Engine NDB Simple Create Read Update

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

What is the best way to store one editable string in Python Google App Engine?  I tried to use NDB, with a single route to create, read, and update the string.   But this does not seem to work:

```
class Storage(ndb.Model):
    content  = ndb.StringProperty()

class CreateReadUpdate(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        entity = ndb.Key(Storage, 'name').get()
        self.response.out.write(entity.content)
    def post(self):
        content = json.loads(self.request.body).get('content')
        entity = ndb.Key(Storage, 'name').get()
        if not entity:
            entity = Storage(content='')
        entity.content = content
        entity.put()
```

Not sure how to debug in this environment.  So I have to ask, what is wrong here?  I just want the simplest App Engine CRUD possible.

Comment: Did you check in the Datastore Viewer if you have anything there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start debugging with logging on dev and on production.

Simple example:

```
import logging

...

logging.info(entity.property)
```

Your problem is that you are not providing a key_name/id for the entity you are saving (if everything else is fine), thus when you try to display it you get nothing.

Change you save logic to this:

```
def post(self):
    content = json.loads(self.request.body).get('content')
    entity = ndb.Key(Storage, 'name').get()
    if not entity:
        entity = Storage(id='name', content='') # see here
    entity.content = content
    entity.put()
```

or as an alternative:

```
def post(self):
    content = json.loads(self.request.body).get('content')
    entity = Storage.get_or_insert('name')
    entity.content = content
    entity.put()
```

If you need an example check "[How to use GAE with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052013/how-to-use-ajax-with-google-app-engine-python/22053890#22053890)" from a previous answer  and [this](https://github.com/jimmykane/gae-voting-ajax-example) is the repo

Comment: For the get request - I imagine Storage.get_by_id('name') will be the right thing to use.  Thanks!

Comment: @benshope yes. Though I prefer using the key construct method as you used. It's more consistent.